# how to clear a listview from another form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I would like to know, how to clear a list view items from an another form. For instance, I have Form A with a ListView, I would like to clear the Form A ListView Items from Form B. What I tried is, create a function in Form A to clear the listView and call that function from Form B. But it is not working. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you post some source code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and easy way to do so; this removes all items from listbox using a for each...

```
      Private Sub btnClearListView_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClearListView.Click

            For Each I In FormA.ListView1.Items
              FormA.ListView1.Items.Remove(I)
            Next

      End Sub
```

Thanks!